# Simple Trigonometry?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

**EDIT - Thanks for all the answers everyone.  I think I accidentally led you slightly wrong as the square in the picture below should be a rectangle (I see most of you are referencing squares which seems like it would make my life a lot easier).  Also, the x/y lines could go in any direction, so the red dot won't always be at the top y boundary.  I was originally going for a y = mx + b solution, but then I got stuck trying to figure out how I know whether to plug in the x or the y (one of them has to be known, obviously).**

I have a very simple question (I think) that I'm currently struggling with for some reason.  I'm trying to have a type of minimap in my game which shows symbols around the perimeter of the view, pointing towards objectives off-screen.

Anyway, I'm trying to find the value of the red point (while the black borders and everything in green is known):

[image]

It seems like simple trigonometry, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around it.  I just need to find the "new" x value from the green point to the red point, then I can utilize basic math to get the red point, but how I go about finding that new x is puzzling me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think you might want to post this question here instead: http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's actually simpler than that. All you need is the equation for the line from x to y (something like y = mx + b, but I'm sure you knew that), and the y value of the boundary. Plug the y value in and solve for x.

Comment: @jpm: Simpler then that even :D

Comment: @KendallFrey Indeed. You got my +1.

Answer (score 4):

```
scale = max(abs(x), abs(y))
x = x / scale
y = y / scale
```

This is the simple case, for a square from (-1, -1) to (1, 1). If you want a different sized square, multiply the coordinates by `sidelen / 2`.

If you want a rectangle instead of a square, use the following formula. (This is another solution to the arbitrarily-sized square version)

```
scale = max(abs(x) / (width / 2), abs(y) / (height / 2))
x = x / scale
y = y / scale
```

Comment: +1… but this is for a unit square (width=2), you should multiply by half the dimension of the square at the end.

Comment: Don't suppose this simplifies nicely using a rectangle instead of a square, does it?  (Or something similar to this method?)

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the length of one side of the square *`l`*.  The slope of the line is *`-y/x`*.  That means, if you move along the line and rise a distance *`y`* toward the top of the square, then you'll move a distance *`x`* to the left.  But since the green point is at the center of the square, you can rise only *`l/2`*.  You can express this as a ratio:

```
    -y   -l/2
    ——— = ———
     x     d
```

Where *`d`* is the distance you'll move to the left.  Solving for *`d`*, we have

```
    d = xl/2y
```

So if the green dot is at `(0, 0)`, the red dot is at

```
(-l/2, xl/2y)
```

.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Thank you.  That was fun.  :-)  Is there a good way to put a fixed-width font inline with regular text, and italicize only some of the fixed-width characters?  I'd be even happier if the background were white instead of gray.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the angle and the width of the square `w`.

If the green dot is at `(0,0)`, then the angle is `a = atan(y/x)`, the y-coordinate of the dot is `w/2`, and therefore the x-coordinate of the dot is `tan(1/a) * (w/2)`. Note that `tan(1/a) == pi/2 - tan(a)`, or in other words the angle you *really* want to plug into `tan` is the one outside the box.

Edit: yes, this can be done without trig, too. All you need is to interpolate the x-coordinate of the dot on the line. So you know the y-coordinate is `w/2`, then the x-coordinate is `(w/2) * x/y`. But, be careful which quadrant of the square you're working with. That formula is only valid for `-y<x<y`, otherwise you want to reverse `x` and `y`.

Comment: Pretty sure this can be done with even less (read: no) trigonometry.

Comment: Yes, I think a solution using similar triangles would be more elegant as it does away with trigonometry completely and the most complex operation it needs is division.